# Same scale on legends for differen charts

Tags: r, ggplot2

I draw two charts but want to have the same scale of dots in both for comparision

```
geofirmen<-data.frame(lon=c(1,2,3), lat=c(1,2,3), freqplz=c(5,10,15))
ggplot(data= geofirmen) + geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, size=freqplz, alpha=.7), colour = "dodgerblue4")
```

and

```
geofirmen<-data.frame(lon=c(1,2,3), lat=c(1,2,3), freqplz=c(5,10,20))
ggplot(data= geofirmen) + geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, size=freqplz, alpha=.7), colour = "dodgerblue4")
```

[image: looks same but is smaller] [image: looks same but is bigger]

It is i want both have the legend scale of the bigger scale.
Attention, the proportion of the graph have not to change since I picture a geografical map but the size of freqplz must be identical for a value of 10 etc.
How does this work?

Comment: if you make this question [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) you will get better help

Comment: Use facets, see e.g. `?facet_wrap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need two separate plots then you can use the same definition of `scale_size()` for both plots (add to both `ggplot()` comands) where you define `breaks=` and also set `limits=` that contains values of both plots.

```
+ scale_size(breaks=c(5,10,15,20),limits=c(0,20))
```

Another solution is to put all data in one data frame that contains grouping column (`group` in example data). Then add `facet_wrap()` to make facets for each level. In this case there will be only one legend. `coord_fixed()` is used to ensure fixed aspect ratio between `x` and `y` axis.

```
geofirmen.new<-data.frame(lon=c(1,2,3,1,2,3), lat=c(1,2,3,1,2,3), 
    freqplz=c(5,10,15,5,10,20),group=c(1,1,1,2,2,2))

ggplot(data= geofirmen.new,aes(x = lon, y = lat, size=freqplz)) + 
    geom_point(alpha=.7, colour = "dodgerblue4") + 
    facet_wrap(~group,ncol=1) + coord_fixed()
```

[image]